# For a Scala map of key to a tuple, how to select (project?) a specific item from the tuple?

Tags: scala, hashmap

Say I have a map with multi-attribute values, of which I want to select a specific attribute.

For instance, a map representing a table of people with name, gender, age, description.

In SQL, I would write "select age from people where name='whomever'"

How would I get that effect in Scala?

```
val people = Map(
 "Walter White" -> ("male",52,"bad boy"),
 "Skyler White" -> ("female",42,"morally challenged mom")
 )

// equivalent of select * from people. This works.
for ((name,(gender,age,desc)) <- people) println(s"$name is a $age year old $gender and is a $desc")

// what should be the syntax to get "the age of Walter White is 52"?
// in SQL, it would be "'The age of Walter White is ' || (select age from people where name='Walter White')"
// what would it be in Scala?
println("The age of Walter White is " + people("Walter White")(1)) // not this!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `Person` case class and create a new map with `Person`s instead of tuples.

```
case class Person(name: String, gender: String, age: Int, description: String)

val persons = people map { case (name, (gender, age, descr)) =>
  name -> Person(name, gender, age, descr)
}
```

This way you could write :

```
persons("Walter White").age              // Int = 52
persons.get("Skyler White").map(_.age)   // Option[Int] = Some(42)
```

You could also access the age using your original code :

```
people("Walter White")._2                // Int = 52
```

Comment: I like this answer as Peter shows several ways to retrieve the data, but just want to discuss the tradeoffs. I think we should always do `persons.get("Skyler White").map(_.age)` . SQL returns no rows if there is no match. So, doing `persons("Walter White").age` is error prone. Also `people("Walter White")._2 ` is shorter but not readable.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Peter, and Rahul too. I wouldn't have figured out how to avoid throwing an exception for a missing key.

Comment: @Rahul You are correct, I didn't really emphasize the importance of using `Option` in my answer, so thanks !